# Christoffel Symbols in terms of the Log Function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

Since the Riemmanian Log function expresses the Manifold structure in terms of $\mathbb{R}^d$ locally, then I was wondering:

Can we express the Christoffel Symbols explicitly in terms of the Log function?

That is if we know Log can we deduce the Christoffel symbols?